# Bootstrap links not working on mobile devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

On the website: www.onlineskateschool.com the links work fine on desktops, but when you go to a mobile device, none of the links work.

I have tried a few different versions of bootstrap, but this has not helped yet. Any ideas where my issue could be?

This can be replicated in Chrome Canary on a desktop with the 'nexus 5' selected after pressing f12 for developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your javascript with your auto reformatting of the menu links is your culprit. The phone's width is too big to change to the mobile menu (3 barred icon that contains the links which work on mobile) but it is too small to work on the original links (the ones you see on a regular desktop). Try resizing your browser's width and you will see what I am talking about.

You should change the js code that has to do with your reformatting and then your links should work.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I am not sure which Javascript code you mean? I am trying to find the js that auto reformats the menu links

Comment: This did not help unfortunately. I have reverted the release.